# Diagnosing outer error in R

Tags: r, runtime-error

I wrote my own function in `R` because I have to solve a problem over a 2 dimensional grid (this corresponds to the values of `A` and `B` in the code) and would like to use the `outer()` function to speed up the code rather than using a double for-loop.  However, the code returns the following error, which I am having a  very hard time understanding:

```
> outer(A,B,f)
Error in outer(A, B, f) : 
  dims [product 56] do not match the length of object [1]
```

I would have expected my code to return 56 p-values since that is what gets returned for scalar inputs to the function `f()`.  Well here is the code:

```
library(survival)

iter = 20
n = 120
ratio = 2
hr = 0.5
med.C = 3
med.T = med.C/hr

A = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7)
B = c(0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95)

f = function(A,B){

        med.C.P = med.C/A
        med.T.P = med.T/A
        med.C.N = med.C
        med.T.N = med.T

        n.T = round(n*ratio/(ratio+1))
        n.C = n - n.T

            n.T.P = rbinom(1, n.T, B)
            n.T.N = n.T - n.T.P
            n.C.P = rbinom(1, n.C, B)
            n.C.N = n.C - n.C.P

            survtime = c(rexp(n.T.P, log(2)/med.T.P), rexp(n.T.N, log(2)/med.T.N), rexp(n.C.P, log(2)/med.C.P), rexp(n.C.N, log(2)/med.C.N))

            stuff = data.frame(arm = c(rep("T", n.T), rep("C", n.C)), dx = c(rep("P", n.T.P), rep("N", n.T.N), rep("P", n.C.P), rep("N", n.C.N)), survtime)

            fit = survfit(Surv(stuff$survtime)~stuff$arm)
            coxfit = coxph(Surv(stuff$survtime)~stuff$arm)

            HR = exp(coxfit$coefficients)
            p.val=summary(coxfit)$logtest["pvalue"]
            return(p.val)

}
```

So I would like to figure out how to use the outer command with my code or an alternative solution to getting the 56 p-values quickly.  I stress that I need fast code because I would like to make my grid finer, and also, will be running this code multiple times to get replications of those values.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `outer` will not work for your function. Here is the a piece of the help file:

> FUN is called with these two extended vectors as arguments (plus any arguments in ...). It must be a vectorized function (or the name of one) expecting at least two arguments and returning a value with the same length as the first (and the second).

Since your function is not vectorized, `outer` is out. :)
I was able to get your function to work with apply:

```
# add elispses
f = function(A,B, ...){
  # keep everything else the same
}
# then apply along with expand.grid
apply(expand.grid(A,B), 1, f, "A"=A, "B"=B)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A naive question, but what does it mean to be vectorized?

Comment: Also, I get this error doing what you suggest: > apply(expand.grid(A,B), 1, f, "A"=A, "B"=B)
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (newX[, i])